# Select all foreign key relationship chains from any set of potentially gapped table names

Tags: postgresql, select, foreign-key

I am using this query to find all foreign key relationships:

```
 SELECT con.relname AS child_table,
    att2.attname AS child_column,
    cl.relname AS parent_table,
    att.attname AS parent_column
   FROM ( 
       SELECT 
         unnest(con1.conkey) AS parent,
         unnest(con1.confkey) AS child,
         con1.confrelid,
         con1.conrelid,
         cl_1.relname
       FROM 
         pg_class cl_1,
         pg_namespace ns,
         pg_constraint con1
       WHERE 
         con1.contype = 'f'::"char" 
         AND cl_1.relnamespace = ns.oid 
         AND con1.conrelid = cl_1.oid
  ) con,
    pg_attribute att,
    pg_class cl,
    pg_attribute att2
  WHERE 
    att.attrelid = con.confrelid 
    AND att.attnum = con.child 
    AND cl.oid = con.confrelid
    AND att2.attrelid = con.conrelid 
    AND att2.attnum = con.parent
```

For any number of tables connected by foreign keys, how can only all of the relevant relationships be selected?

Take for example this relationship tree:

```
progenitor
    grandparent_a
        parent_a_1
        parent_a_2
    grandparent_b
        parent_b_1
        parent_b_2
```

That is a simple example, and my trees have many many layers, but I'd like, from an arbitrary amount of tables, be able to get all of the linking foreign key relationships.

If I wanted to select data from both `parent_a_1` and `parent_a_2`, the two relationships to `grandparent_a` would be selected.

If I wanted to select data from both `parent_b_1` and `parent_a_1`, all relationships from both to `progenitor` would be selected.

I can do this when all tables are immediately connected, but I can't conceptualize how to connect the gaps.

Comment: What do you mean by "potentially gapped"?

Comment: You're trying to find all connected edges in a graph, right? i.e. the set of tables that have direct or indirect FK relationships to each other, and all the relationships that build that set.

Comment: @CraigRinger Yes, to your last comment.  I will add more detail in an edit.  Thank you for your help.